# JSON en Angular 6

Tags: json, angular

Estoy con un problema para el manejo de Json en Angular.

El Json es:

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "2287947",
        "chattime": "1544102153",
        "chat": "Finalizado",
        "chattype": "text",
        "media": "",
        "outgoing": "0",
        "bot": "0",
        "unread": "1",
        "email_created": ""
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2287931",
        "chattime": "1544102141",
        "chat": "asdasdasd",
        "chattype": "text",
        "media": "",
        "outgoing": "1",
        "bot": "0",
        "unread": "0",
        "email_created": "api"
    }
}
```

Y en el html de Angular le tengo un for

```
<div *ngFor="let chat of chats">
{{chat.id}}
</div>
```

Pero me dice este error:

**ERROR Error: "Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays."**

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que angular no te permite iterar en la plantilla un objeto, si no que debe ser un array, para ello has lo siguiente:

```
chats= {
    "0": {
        "id": "2287947",
        "chattime": "1544102153",
        "chat": "Finalizado",
        "chattype": "text",
        "media": "",
        "outgoing": "0",
        "bot": "0",
        "unread": "1",
        "email_created": ""
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2287931",
        "chattime": "1544102141",
        "chat": "asdasdasd",
        "chattype": "text",
        "media": "",
        "outgoing": "1",
        "bot": "0",
        "unread": "0",
        "email_created": "api"
    }

chats = Object.keys(chats).map(e=>chats[e]);
```

si imprimes el valor, puedes ver que los "key" del JSON se convierten en array, y en el template pueden iterarse sin problema alguno.

Espero te sirva.

**Fuente o Referencia**

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40521167/convert-json-object-in-to-array-to-iterate-through-ng-repeat-using-javascript/40521237

Comment: Gracias Miguel!

Comment: Con mucho gusto! ;)